# CSS Selector - how to select the first and last div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am having trouble selecting the first and last div for the following html markup:

```
<div class="layout__side">
  <div class="portlet-dropzone">

      <div id="id1">
        <span></span>
        <div class="portlet-body">
          <div class="portlet-borderless-container">
            <div class="portlet-body">
              <article id="id2">
                <div class="inner">
                  <header>yoyoyoyoyoyoy</header>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--end id1 div-->

      <div id="id3">
        <span></span>
        <div class="portlet-body">
          <div class="portlet-borderless-container">
            <div class="portlet-body">
              <article id="id4">
                <div class="inner">
                  <header>yoyoyoyoyoyoy</header>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--end id3 div-->

      <div id="id5">
        <span></span>
        <div class="portlet-body">
          <div class="portlet-borderless-container">
            <div class="portlet-body">
              <article id="id6">
                <div class="inner">
                  <header>yoyoyoyoyoyoy</header>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--end id5 div-->

      <div id="id7">
        <span></span>
        <div class="portlet-body">
          <div class="portlet-borderless-container">
            <div class="portlet-body">
              <article id="id8">
                <div class="inner">
                  <header>yoyoyoyoyoyoy</header>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--end id7 div-->

      <div id="id9">
        <span></span>
        <div class="portlet-body">
          <div class="portlet-borderless-container">
            <div class="portlet-body">
              <article id="id10">
                <div class="inner">
                  <header>yoyoyoyoyoyoy</header>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--end id9 div-->

      <div id="id11">
        <span></span>
        <div class="portlet-body">
          <div class="portlet-borderless-container">
            <div class="portlet-body">
              <article id="id12">
                <div class="inner">
                  <header>yoyoyoyoyoyoy</header>
                </div>
              </article>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--end id11 div-->

  </div><!--end portlet-dropzone-->

</div><!--end layout__side-->
```

I am trying to select and style only the id1 div header without explicitly selecting it using the div id. I tried using the div:first-child selector, but all of the divs are being selected! This is what I tried, along with using nth-child(1)

```
.layout__side .portlet-dropzone div:first-child header{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you're selecting **all `div` descendant** elements that are a first child.

In other words, the descendant `div` elements `.portlet-borderless-container`, `.portlet-body`, and `.inner` are selected (since they are descendants of `.portlet-dropzone` and they are the first child relative to their parent element). Since all the `div` elements are selected, each `header` element is thereby selected and styled.

You need to select the direct child `div` element instead (by using the [direct child combinator, `>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#child-selectors)). In doing so, only the `div` element that is a direct child of `.portlet-dropzone` will be selected if it is the first child.

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/wcs3g93k/)

```
.layout__side .portlet-dropzone > div:first-child header {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

As your title suggests, if you also want to select the last one:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4yy4pf0y/)

```
.layout__side .portlet-dropzone > div:first-child header,
.layout__side .portlet-dropzone > div:last-child header  {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

---

It's also worth pointing out that there are [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) and [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) pseudo classes which will select the first/last element by *type* (unlike `:first-child`/`:last-child` which will select based on the index only rather than the type).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/zxm2fom4/)

```
.layout__side .portlet-dropzone > div:first-of-type header,
.layout__side .portlet-dropzone > div:last-of-type header  {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This may be useful if there are elements of varying types and you only want to target the `div` elements. For instance, if there was a random `h1` element before the first `div`, like in the example above, the first `div` would still be selected.

Comment: Thank-you so much! Yeah, I guess I still have a long way to go in understanding CSS selectors!